# python/ruby regex for domain in text

Tags: python, regex, ruby

I have text as result i need to find all domains on this text, domains with subdomain and without with https and without;

```
opt-i.mydomain.com 'www-oud.mydomain.com'
https\\u003a\\u002f\\u002fapi.noddos.com\\u002fabout\\u002fen-us\\u002fsignin\\u002f"
<script type="text/javascript">
       (function(){
  var baseUrl = 'https\x3A\x2F\x2Fhubspot.mydomain.com';
  var baseUrl = 'https\x3A\x2F\x2Fhub-spot.mydomain.com';
</script>
#=========================================================
define("modules/constants/env", [], function() {
    return {"BATCH_THUMB_ENDPOINTS": [], "LIVE_TRANSCODE_SERVER": "showbox-tr.dropbox.com", "STATIC_CONTENT_HOST": "cfl.dropboxstatic.com", "NOTES_WEBSERVER": "paper.dropbox.com", "REDIRECT_SAFE_ORIGINS": ["www.dropbox.com", "dropbox.com", "api.dropboxapi.com", "api.dropbox.com", "linux.dropbox.com", "photos.dropbox.com", "carousel.dropbox.com", "client-web.dropbox.com", "services.pp.dropbox.com", "www.dropbox.com", "docsend.com", "paper.dropbox.com", "notes.dropbox.com", "test.composer.dropbox.com", "showcase.dropbox.com", "collections.dropbox.com", "embedded.hellosign.com", "help.dropbox.com", "help-stg.dropbox.com", "experience.dropbox.com", "learn.dropbox.com", "learn-stage.dropbox.com", "app.hellosign.com", "replay.dropbox.com"], "PROF_SHARING_WEBSERVER": "showcase.dropbox.com", "FUNCAPTCHA_SERVER": "dropboxcaptcha.com", "__esModule": true};
});
#========================================================
https://mydomain.co/path/2
https://api.mydomain.co/path/2
https://api-v1.mydomain.co/path/2
https://superdomain.com:443
https://api.superdomain.com:443
https\\u003a\\u002f\\u002fapi.noddos.com\\u002fabout\\u002fen-us\\u002fsignin\\u002f"
https\\u003a\\u002f\\u002fnoddos.com\\u002fabout\\u002fen-us\\u002fsignin\\u002f"
root.I13N_config.location = "https:\u002F\u002Flocation.com\u002Faccount\u002Fchallenge\u002Frecaptcha
root.I13N_config.location = "https:\u002F\u002Fapi.location.com\u002Faccount\u002Fchallenge\u002Frecaptcha
&scope=openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.domain2.com%2Fv2%2FOfficeHome.All&response_mode=form_post&nonce
&scope=openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fdomain2.com%2Fv2%2FOfficeHome.All&response_mode=form_post&nonce
```

https%3a%2f%2fwww.anotherdomain.com%2fv2%2
i try this regex but its not capture all i need.

```
re.compile(
        r'''((?<=x2[fF]|02[fF]|%2[fF])|(?<=//))(\w\.|\w[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}\w\.){1,3}[A-Za-z]{2,6}|(?<=["'])(\w\.|\w[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}\w\.){1,3}[A-Za-z]{2,6}(?=["'])''',
        re.VERBOSE)
```

captured result by regex:

```
{'showbox-tr.dropbox.com', 'api.dropbox.com', 'api-v1.mydomain.co', 'www-oud.mydomain.com', 'cfl.dropboxstatic.com', 'hub-spot.mydomain.com', 'paper.dropbox.com', 'superdomain.com', 'api.superdomain.com', 'linux.dropbox.com', 'embedded.hellosign.com', 'api.location.com', 'api.dropboxapi.com', 'www.dropbox.com', 'location.com', 'api.domain2.com', 'dropbox.com', 'api.noddos.com', 'dropboxcaptcha.com', 'learn-stage.dropbox.com', 'test.composer.dropbox.com', 'help-stg.dropbox.com', 'replay.dropbox.com', 'domain2.com', 'hubspot.mydomain.com', 'learn.dropbox.com', 'help.dropbox.com', 'collections.dropbox.com', 'app.hellosign.com', 'api.mydomain.co', 'noddos.com', 'docsend.com', 'mydomain.co', 'notes.dropbox.com', 'photos.dropbox.com', 'client-web.dropbox.com', 'services.pp.dropbox.com', 'OfficeHome.All', 'showcase.dropbox.com', 'carousel.dropbox.com', 'experience.dropbox.com'}
```

expected results so in general its not capture "opt-i.mydomain.com":

```
{'opt-i.mydomain.com', 'hubspot.mydomain.com', 'embedded.hellosign.com', 'carousel.dropbox.com', 'api.dropboxapi.com', 'experience.dropbox.com', 'linux.dropbox.com', 'api.superdomain.com', 'noddos.com', 'showcase.dropbox.com', 'app.hellosign.com', 'www-oud.mydomain.com', 'showbox-tr.dropbox.com', 'help-stg.dropbox.com', 'api.domain2.com', 'notes.dropbox.com', 'paper.dropbox.com', 'services.pp.dropbox.com', 'collections.dropbox.com', 'learn.dropbox.com', 'location.com', 'api.location.com', 'docsend.com', 'api.dropbox.com', 'replay.dropbox.com', 'mydomain.co', 'hub-spot.mydomain.com', 'www.dropbox.com', 'learn-stage.dropbox.com', 'domain2.com', 'help.dropbox.com', 'api.mydomain.co', 'api-v1.mydomain.co', 'superdomain.com', 'dropboxcaptcha.com', 'api.noddos.com', 'dropbox.com', 'test.composer.dropbox.com', 'cfl.dropboxstatic.com', 'client-web.dropbox.com', 'opt-i.mydomain.com', 'photos.dropbox.com'}
```

i also test this regex it match all domains better than previus but problem is with doamin`s that has unicode example:

```
"https\\u003a\\u002f\\u002fapi.noddos.com" will capture "u002fapi.noddos.com" but we need "api.noddos.com"

re.compile(
        r'''
        ([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9]
        ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
regex = r"(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9]"
data = """opt-i.mydomain.com 'www-oud.mydomain.com'
https\\u003a\\u002f\\u002fapi.noddos.com\\u002fabout\\u002fen-us\\u002fsignin\\u002f"
<script type="text/javascript">
       (function(){
  var baseUrl = 'https\x3A\x2F\x2Fhubspot.mydomain.com';
  var baseUrl = 'https\x3A\x2F\x2Fhub-spot.mydomain.com';
</script>
#=========================================================
define("modules/constants/env", [], function() {
    return {"BATCH_THUMB_ENDPOINTS": [], "LIVE_TRANSCODE_SERVER": "showbox-tr.dropbox.com", "STATIC_CONTENT_HOST": "cfl.dropboxstatic.com", "NOTES_WEBSERVER": "paper.dropbox.com", "REDIRECT_SAFE_ORIGINS": ["www.dropbox.com", "dropbox.com", "api.dropboxapi.com", "api.dropbox.com", "linux.dropbox.com", "photos.dropbox.com", "carousel.dropbox.com", "client-web.dropbox.com", "services.pp.dropbox.com", "www.dropbox.com", "docsend.com", "paper.dropbox.com", "notes.dropbox.com", "test.composer.dropbox.com", "showcase.dropbox.com", "collections.dropbox.com", "embedded.hellosign.com", "help.dropbox.com", "help-stg.dropbox.com", "experience.dropbox.com", "learn.dropbox.com", "learn-stage.dropbox.com", "app.hellosign.com", "replay.dropbox.com"], "PROF_SHARING_WEBSERVER": "showcase.dropbox.com", "FUNCAPTCHA_SERVER": "dropboxcaptcha.com", "__esModule": true};
});
#========================================================
https://mydomain.co/path/2
https://api.mydomain.co/path/2
https://api-v1.mydomain.co/path/2
https://superdomain.com:443
https://api.superdomain.com:443
https\\u003a\\u002f\\u002fapi.noddos.com\\u002fabout\\u002fen-us\\u002fsignin\\u002f"
https\\u003a\\u002f\\u002fnoddos.com\\u002fabout\\u002fen-us\\u002fsignin\\u002f"
root.I13N_config.location = "https:\u002F\u002Flocation.com\u002Faccount\u002Fchallenge\u002Frecaptcha
root.I13N_config.location = "https:\u002F\u002Fapi.location.com\u002Faccount\u002Fchallenge\u002Frecaptcha
&scope=openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.domain2.com%2Fv2%2FOfficeHome.All&response_mode=form_post&nonce
&scope=openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fdomain2.com%2Fv2%2FOfficeHome.All&response_mode=form_post&nonce"""

data = re.sub(r"u[0-9a-z]{4}", "", data)

matches = re.findall(regex, data)

#output matches:
['opt-i.mydomain.com', 'www-oud.mydomain.com', 'api.noddos.com', 'ht.mydomain.com', 'hub-spot.mydomain.com', 'showbox-tr.dropbox.com', 'cfl.dropboxstatic.com', 'paper.dropbox.com', 'www.dropbox.com', 'dropbox.com', 'api.dropboxapi.com', 'api.dropbox.com', 'linux.dropbox.com', 'photos.dropbox.com', 'carousel.dropbox.com', 'client-web.dropbox.com', 'services.pp.dropbox.com', 'www.dropbox.com', 'docsend.com', 'paper.dropbox.com', 'notes.dropbox.com', 'test.composer.dropbox.com', 'showcase.dropbox.com', 'collections.dropbox.com', 'embedded.hellosign.com', 'help.dropbox.com', 'help-stg.dropbox.com', 'experience.dropbox.com', 'learn.dropbox.com', 'learn-stage.dropbox.com', 'app.hellosign.com', 'replay.dropbox.com', 'showcase.dropbox.com', 'dropboxcaptcha.com', 'mydomain.co', 'api.mydomain.co', 'api-v1.mydomain.co', 'somain.com', 'api.somain.com', 'api.noddos.com', 'noddos.com', 'config.location', 'location.com', 'config.location', 'api.location.com', 'api.domain2.com', 'domain2.com']
```

Comment: this match to 'u002fapi.noddos.com' and need to match ''api.noddos.com'

Comment: check my edit @00435

Comment: hi thx works but now when i get in content "https%3a%2f%2fwww.anotherdomain.com%2fv2%2"  its capture "2fwww.anotherdomain.com"